# What costs more data, ASCII or HEX?

Tags: udp, hex, ascii

I'm dealing with a device that has both options to send data through UDP connection. As I couldn't find any comparison or something, could someone explain the difference in processing both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hex data transfers a byte as two hex characters, using only 4 bits of the available 8 bits. Ascii data transfers either 7bits or 8bits at a time, thus using the full range of 0..255 while a hex character only transfers 0..15.

For example, the number 18 is transferred as 12 hex coded (taking up two bytes) but as 18 ascii-encoded(taking up one byte 00010002).